# Lotus Notes: outline not shown when open a view from a new db

Tags: view, lotus-notes, outline

```
Call ws.OpenDatabase("ServerName","NewA2.nsf","Myview", doc.Field_T(0), False, False)
```

The view is opened correctly - selecting the docs categorized by `Field_T`, but an outline which is situated in the left side of the frameset is not shown.

I appreciate your time & Help!

- The outline is situated on a frame, and also the frame name where the view is situated is specified in the outline entry where is the view `Myview`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name the frames of your Frameset according to Notes- standards, then this will work by default: Name the left Frame as "NotesNavigation" and the right frame as "NotesView", then views will automatically open in this frameset in the right place

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to solve this via code, but two things to try:

1. See if it helps changing the database properties to default to launching with the desired frameset.
2. Try the suggestion on this blog post:  http://naveegator.blogspot.com/2011/12/open-frameset-of-another-database-in.html?m=1

Neither is perfect but perhaps they'll get you close enough.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Ken. 1. I already tried but same result. 2. In this case I cannot ( or at least I don't know how ) to scroll to the category called Field_T. Hope there is a solution